# How to find details of the dir creation in linux

Tags: linux, file, datetime

I need to find the exact time at which one directory was created in Linux.
I did :

ls -lart for long listing

for which output is like :

drwxr-xr-x  2 sugagraw dba 4096 Nov 10 20:41 debug

Is there a command by which I can find the exact time (ie: miliseconds also) of this directory creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for last modification datetime:

```
stat -c %y MyDirectory
```

and this for creation datetime:

```
stat -c %w MyDirectory
```

BTW: The creation datetime is only available on these filesystems:

ufs2, zfs, ext4, btrfs, jfs

Comment: :( sorry... It gives the long listing but of the time the directory was last modified, not created.

Comment: stat is the right tool for this, but `%y` is the last modification time, not the creation time. You might try `%w` (time of file birth) but that is usually unknown on POSIX systems.